# Android - Listview onItemClickListener always gives 4

Tags: java, android, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

My application will respond to a user selection on a listview, and then pass the selected item to another activity. But, no matter what listview item is selected, this code will pass index=4.

Main.java:

```
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, 
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles)));

ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
            i.putExtra("index", ""+position);
            startActivity(i);
      }
   });
```

And the 'Challengeview.class' that the intent is sent to

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("index");
```

From here, the 'value' is used to refer to an array index. Logcat is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
```

EDIT: Titles Array, as stored in values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="titles">
        <item>Challenge1</item>
        <item>Challenge2</item>
        <item>Challenge3</item> 
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you post you titles array?

Comment: Sorry, forgot! Done! :)

Comment: You can get the string at that position and pass the same

Comment: @TimJ Sorry, position also starts from `0`.

Comment: @TimJ change to  `i.putExtra("index", position);` and use `getIntExtra`. also you could use `String s = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)` and pass the string

Comment: @TimJ did you try the suggestion in my previous comment??

Comment: Sorry, I was working on it :)
I tried this:
'         int pos = (int) lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Challengeview.class);
        i.getIntExtra("index", position-1 );
              startActivity(i); '

And with still the same error :( Sorry about the poor code editing, couldnt quite get it to work

Comment: Imo it is impossible. Are you doing something strange in your adapter? Do you have any footervier or headerview? From the snippet you posted there is no reason why it should not work

Comment: Thats pretty much it, apart from converting the passed string 'value' into a integer and using a 2D array for the data storage and selection. No footer or headerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complete solution of your answer...

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources()
                        .getStringArray(R.array.titles));
        lv.setAdapter(array);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("index", value);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String pos = b.getString("index");
        tv.setText("Position = " + pos);
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**second.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>'
```

**res/values/string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">TestProject</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <string-array name="titles">
        <item>Challenge1</item>
        <item>Challenge2</item>
        <item>Challenge3</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```